# Unique symmetrical elements Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

I have a Numpy array as this:

```
 [1 4]
 [2 3]
 [3 0]
 [4 1]
 [5 6]
 [6 5]
 [7 6]]
```

This is output of `NearestNeighbors` algorithm of `scikit-learn`. I want to remove duplicated values. To have something like this:

```
[[0 3]
 [1 4]
 [2 3]
 [6 5]
 [7 6]]
```

I searched a lot, but not found any solution.

Comment: `np.unique(np.sort(a, axis=1), axis=0)`?

Comment: @Divakar Brilliant!!! Thanks a lot! I tried all the way I could, even I tried to flip the array and then compared it, but couldn't make it out!

Comment: But it would have`[5, 6],` and yours has `[6,5]`.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, but it's Ok to me. Because all I wanted is to have a unique array of `NearestNeighbors` indices. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with sorting and `np.unique` -

```
np.unique(np.sort(a, axis=1), axis=0)
```